# vuejs: How to change the class of each item in v-for

Tags: class, vue.js, bind, v-for

My component template have an img

```
<img src="img/loading.gif" :data-src="url" class="live-snapshot-img" :class="{lazy:true, 'lazy-loaded': false}">
```

When it rendered, I'll trigger out the lazy event. The class will changed to 'lazy-loaded' from 'lazy'.

```
<img src="img/loading.gif" :data-src="url" class="live-snapshot-img lazy-loaded">
```

Then if the data changed, I want the class change back to 'lazy'. The bind:class doesn't work.

Comment: You're not binding to anything, you have hardcoded the values. lazy = true, lazy-loaded = false

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this in slightly the wrong way. You have the right idea, but I feel like your thinking and jQuery post render dom manipulation manner, not that this is bad, just not right for this situation. Vue works a little differently. If you want to change the class after the event in this particular instance, you bind your :class to a variable in your vue component.

If I wanted to make this happen, I would probably start by setting a variables in my component data for the state. (see: [Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax))

```
Vue.component('my-component-name', {
     data: function () {
          return {
               imageState: {'lazy': true, 'lazy-loaded': false}
          }
     }
})
```

Then bind that to your element:

```
<img src="img/loading.gif" :data-src="url" class="live-snapshot-img" :class="imageState">
```

You can then manipulate the imageState in your component methods in any way you want.

Comment: Thank you, but the component method doesn't work. I think Vue execute the function every time, but it find imageStatue not changed. So vue abandon to render it.

Comment: Just as I think, Vue doesn't render the value not changed. I use a random class name to crack it. But I think there should be a better way.

Comment: You should post more of your code, specifically the methods you are using to manipulate the imageState. Perhaps post your entire component somewhere so we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is
Create a method in component

```
    lazyload: function() {
        var clazz = {lazy: true, 'lazy-loaded': false}
        clazz['dummy' + Math.random()] = true
        return clazz
    },
```

and change the img to

```
<img src="img/loading.gif" :data-src="url" class="live-snapshot-img" :class="lazyload()">
```